# Centering Horizontal in visual format language

Tags: swift, visual-format-language

I have 3 labels which I have placed against each other like in this picture:

[image]

However right now they are placed against the left side, I wan't them to be placed in the center horizontal. Here is the visual format code for their horizontal placing:

```
let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|[label][label2][label3]|",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)
```

However whatever I test I can't get them to center, any thoughts?

Comment: The easiest solution by far is to put those 3 labels into a view and center that view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make it center horizontally/vertically both as i understand from the image you can make it like this:

```
// Center horizontally
var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "V:[superview]-(<=1)-[label2]",
    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX,
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["superview":view,"label2":label2])

view.addConstraints(constraints)

// Center vertically
constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "H:[superview]-(<=1)-[label1][label2][label3]",
    options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY,
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["superview":view, "label1":label1,"label2":label2,"label3":label3])

view.addConstraints(constraints)
```

so it will be look like this:
[image]

Comment: This is how I want it. But how would you do if it was an even number of labels? Lets say 4?

Comment: What should I use if the views I want to center are inside a UICollectionViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the right-most label is expanding to consume all of the remaining space. To achieve the expected outcome, we have to do two things:

1. Change the VFL to explicitly set each of the label widths to be the same. You can do this by changing the format to `H:|[label1][label2(==label1)][label3(==label1)]|`
2. Modify your labels to center align their text using the `textAlignment` property.

You can drop the following into a playground to get a better feel for what's going on:

```
import UIKit

let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)

let label1 = UILabel()
label1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
label1.layer.borderWidth = 1
label1.text = "Label 1"
label1.textAlignment = .Center
label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label1.sizeToFit()

let label2 = UILabel()
label2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
label2.layer.borderWidth = 1
label2.text = "Label 2"
label2.textAlignment = .Center
label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label2.sizeToFit()

let label3 = UILabel()
label3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
label3.layer.borderWidth = 1
label3.text = "Label 3"
label3.textAlignment = .Center
label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label3.sizeToFit()

let view = UIView(frame: frame)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
view.addSubview(label1)
view.addSubview(label2)
view.addSubview(label3)

let originalFormat = "H:|[label1][label2][label3]|"
let newFormat = "H:|[label1][label2(==label1)][label3(==label1)]|"
let views = ["label1": label1, "label2": label2, "label3": label3]
let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(originalFormat, options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

view.addConstraints(constraints)
view.layoutIfNeeded()

view
```

Using the `originalFormat` you get this:
[image: Output using originalFormat]

With my proposed changes you get this:
[image: Output using newFormat]